# Adjacency Matrix not giving output corresponding to Vertex Labels

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following Graph:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 6}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

This gives the following Graph:

[image]

The corresponding AdjacencyMatrix yields

```
AdjacencyMatrix[g1]
```

[image]

Now, clearly the entries should be

```
{1,3} -> 1
{2,3} -> 1
{3,4} -> 1
{4,5} -> 1
{4,6} -> 1
```

How can I get the expected output?

System: Win10 @ Mathematica v12.3 Student Edition

Comment: Can you create the graph with `Graph[Range[6], {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` instead?

Comment: @MarcoB thank you for finding that.

Answer (score 0):

The result is as designed. Let us look in the documentation to `AdjacencyMatrix`:

> "The vertices Subscript[v, i] are assumed to be in the order given by `VertexList[g]`"

Now

```
VertexList[Graph[{1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 6},VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

> `{1,3,2,4,5,6}`

You may look in the documentation to `VertexList` on your own (There is an example on this theme in it.).